How to reduce the height of the select elements in fluent ui
I want to reduce the height of fluent ui select element:
Here is my select element
I want the dropdown height to be limited to the blue line, and any additional values should appears below like this
Here is my dropdown component
import * as React from "react";
import { Select, useId } from "@fluentui/react-components";
import type { SelectProps } from "@fluentui/react-components";

const Dropdown = (props: SelectProps) => {
    const selectId = useId();

    return (
        <>
            <Select
                style={{
                    maxWidth: "80%",
                    maxHeight: "80px"
                }}
                id={selectId}
                {...props}
            >
                <option>Blue</option>
                <option>Red</option>
                <option>Green</option>
                <option>Yellow</option>
                <option>Orange</option>
                <option>Purple</option>
                <option>Pink</option>
                <option>Brown</option>
                <option>Black</option>
                <option>White</option>
                <option>White</option>
                <option>White</option>
                <option>White</option>
                <option>White</option>
                <option>White</option>
                <option>White</option>
                <option>White</option>
                <option>White</option>
                <option>White</option>
                <option>White</option>
            </Select>
        </>
    );
};

export default Dropdown;

